# How to use the WITH clause in an SQLite trigger

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create a log of certain things in an SQLite database.  I am doing this with a trigger, but I need to insert multiple log records and they all need to have the same timestamp.  In order to do this, I am trying to use a `WITH` clause to get the current timestamp which I can then use in multiple places.

My statement looks something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test7_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON test7 
BEGIN
    WITH t(t) AS (
        SELECT CAST((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000 
                    AS INTEGER)
    )
    INSERT INTO ChangeLog (t, rowid, field, value)
    VALUES 
    (t.t, 1, 'field1', new.field1),
    (t.t, 1, 'field2', new.field2),
    (t.t, 1, 'field3', new.field3);
END;
```

But when I try to run this statement I get a syntax error near "INSERT".  I have renamed the other INSERTs to isolate it to the INSERT statement inside the trigger itself.  Everything works outside the trigger, and when I consulted the SQLite documentation on [TRIGGER](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html),  I noticed that only update, insert, delete, and select statements are allowed inside the trigger - apparently omitting the WITH clause.

How can I achieve the same effect so that I can reuse the same timestamp value in multiple places in the query?

Comment: I believe that **WITH** uses a CTE (Common Table Expression) and [TRIGGER](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) includes ***Common table expression are not supported for statements inside of triggers.***

Comment: Partially `CTE` could be available in a `trigger` through a "additional/external" `CTE-view` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rewrite it as:

```
INSERT INTO ChangeLog (t, rowid, field, value)
SELECT ":1", ":2", ":3",CAST((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000  AS INTEGER)
FROM (VALUES
(t.t, 1, 'field1', new.field1),
(t.t, 1, 'field2', new.field1),
(t.t, 1, 'field3', new.field1) ) sub;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=3666a9eb92396eca15e9cec4138df0d1)**

EDIT:

```
WITH cte(c1,c2,c3,c4) AS (
  VALUES  (t.t, 1, 'field1', new.field1),
          (t.t, 1, 'field2', new.field1),
          (t.t, 1, 'field3', new.field1) 
)
INSERT INTO ChangeLog (t, rowid, field, value)
SELECT c1,c2,c3, CAST((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000  AS INTEGER)
FROM cte;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=ddf0559d6c95def8c92bad11c5c63531)**

---

EDIT:

```
INSERT INTO ChangeLog (t, rowid, field, value)
SELECT c1,c2,c3, CAST((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000  AS INTEGER)
FROM (
    SELECT t.t AS c1, 1 AS c2, 'field1' AS c3, new.field1 AS c4 UNION ALL
    SELECT t.t AS c1, 1 AS c2, 'field2' AS c3, new.field1 AS c4 UNION ALL
    SELECT t.t AS c1, 1 AS c2, 'field3' AS c3, new.field1 AS c4;
) sub
```

Comment: t appears to be in the wrong spot which is easily fixed, but when this runs as a trigger I am seeing a literal ":1", ":2", etc. as field values.  I assume it's supposed to substitute the first, second, etc. values diretly in?

Comment: also, something goofy is going on in the Fiddle, or at least I don't understand... in your Fiddle, ":1" is going into "t", which I would expect to be 1, 2, 3.  But in fact it's the second column which is all 1s.  Why is this?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using "*" instead of ":1", ":2" etc. which I am having trouble finding documentation for, for SQLite but I assume they are parameter bindings of some type which maybe are not allowed inside a trigger.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation on anonymous ("VALUES ...") and positional (":1") values you are using?  I'm turning up nothing but they seem to work to some degree...

Comment: Hmm, I *really* need to be able to use ":1", etc. when logging updates, because I need to be able to insert only fields that change so I need to be able to include a comparator and not include it in the select... but it doesn't seem to work in a trigger!

Comment: @Michael I posted version that does not depend on `:position`

Comment: thanks, unfortunately `WITH` can't be used in a trigger, which was the original issue which triggered the question.  However, for cases where I need to access the individual fields (linked question) I have found that I can use the "UNION ALL" trick works.