# Using an SQLite trigger to log field values that change in an update

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to log updates to field in an SQLite table.  I'm already able to log [INSERTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50748902/how-to-use-the-with-clause-in-an-sqlite-trigger), using something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER _test7_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON test7 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ChangeLog (rid, field, value, tms)
    SELECT *,CAST((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000  AS INTEGER)
    FROM (VALUES
            (new.rowid, 'field1', new.field1),
            (new.rowid, 'field2', new.field2),
            (new.rowid, 'field3', new.field3)
     ) sub;
END;
```

This is apparently using anonymous values, which I haven't been able to find specific documentation on but it seems to work in creating a static table which I can then select to insert into the log table.

However, for updates, I only want to log fields that actually change, so if for example a table had 20 fields and only 1 changed due to an update I would only want 1 row added to the change table, not 20. I have a trigger which looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER _test7_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE on test7
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ChangeLog (rid, field, value, tms)
    SELECT "" AS rid,
           ":1" AS field,
           ":2" AS value,
      CAST((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000  AS INTEGER) AS tms
    FROM (VALUES
        (old.rowid, 'field1', new.field1, new.field1=old.field1),
        (old.rowid, 'field2', new.field2, new.field2=old.field2),
        (old.rowid, 'field3', new.field3, new.field3=old.field3)
     ) sub
    WHERE ":4"=1;
END;
```

But nothing is ever inserted when I do an update!  If I remove the extra comparison field and remove the "WHERE" clause, I see three rows added, but instead of the `rid`, `field`, and `value` being added, I see the literal values "", ":1", and ":2".  I haven't found much documentation on these numbered parameters - the [SQLite language page](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) under the "Parameters" section mentions them in passing but gives very little info on them - and in fact it doesn't even explain why ":1" is actually the *second* parameter and "" is the first!  I should add that I have experimented with using a very similar SELECT outside of a trigger, putting constant values in the VALUES table and it works perfectly!  Specifically:

```
SELECT "" AS a, ":1" AS b, ":2" AS c, ":3" AS d
FROM (VALUES
    (11,22,33,44),
    (111,122,133,144),
    (211,222,233,244)
) sub;
```

returns a table containing the literal values, columns labelled as "a", "b", "c", and "d".  But the same basic structure in a trigger returns literal strings with colons instead of the actual values expected.

I had this bright idea of creating a temporary table with an extra field, selecting everything into it, then selecting everything except the comparison into the real log table.  This does not work as CREATE is not supported in a trigger)

I also tried creating ChangeLog to have an extra field to hold the fifth field in the comparison (e.g. new.fieldx = old.fieldx) but when I use the WHERE clause to only select fields that changed, I go back to having nothing inserted again.

Is there some other way I should be going about this, or am I doing something wrong with how I am handling the positional parameters?

**UPDATE**: I have been experimenting and have found that under some circumstances the positional parameters actually have values, but they are rather nonsensical:

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=dc359c0c1ced42f3f3b968b161f1c482)

Specifically, the field `""` returns the value of the *second* parameter, and the field `":1"` returns the value of the *fourth* parameter.  Why?  How do I reference the first and third parameter?

**UPDATE 2**: After playing around with this a bit more, it appears that the "", ":1", ":2" etc. parameters work fine, so long as there are only constant values in the VALUES table.  Any actual values I insert such as from new, old, etc. - columns which I actually need - are completely ignored as if those columns aren't even there!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER _test7_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE on test7
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ChangeLog (rid, field, value, tms)
    SELECT rowid, field, value, 
        CAST((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000  AS INTEGER)
        FROM (
        SELECT 0 rowid, '' field, 0 value, 0 keep
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sub.* FROM (VALUES
           (old.rowid, 'field1', new.field1, new.field1!=old.field1),
           (old.rowid, 'field2', new.field2, new.field2!=old.field2),
           (old.rowid, 'field3', new.field3, new.field3!=old.field3)
        ) AS sub
    ) WHERE keep=1;
END
```

The trick is using `UNION ALL` to bind field names from a dummy row to the constant rows that follow, and then filtering out the dummy row.

Comment: Just stick a `WHERE FALSE` (or `WHERE 0` in older versions) on the dummy `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

The modification is not taken into account when the old value was NULL or the new value is now NULL. It seems the old and new values are not perceived as different...